# What's reliable way of finding declared but undefined functions/symbols in several interrelated packages?

Tags: packages, variable-definitions

I have many packages some of which use some of others.  I have many symbols defined in them.  Is there a reliable way of finding declared/exported but undefined functions/symbols in several interrelated packages?

Comment: You mean, to filter all the names in a given context leaving only those without any values defined on them?

Comment: My ``PackageManipulations` `` package, available [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/additional_resources.html), has the functionality to track escaping symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is an answer to [Rojo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/109/rojo)'s interpretation (which I agree with) of that question:

```
Select[Names["Global`*"], (First[ToBoxes@Definition[#]] === "Null") &]
```

Replace `` "Global`" `` with context of interest.

Maybe doesn't look neat but works well so far. It is based on an assumption that `Definition` of a symbol without any values will return  `Interpretation[Null,Definition[...]]`

---

Another method not based on boxes:

```
With[{
  info = {Attributes, DefaultValues, DownValues, FormatValues, 
    Messages, OwnValues, SubValues, UpValues, NValues}
  },
  Select[
     Names["Global`*"],
     {} === Flatten @ Through[
        info[ToExpression[#, StandardForm, Unevaluated]]
     ] &
  ]
]
```

or something less documented

```
Select[
  Names["Global`*"],
  {} === ToExpression[ #, StandardForm, 
     Echo @* Flatten @* Values @* Values @* First @* 
     Language`ExtendedFullDefinition 
  ] &
]
```

Both ideas stolen from [Triggering actions when a variable is set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23984/5478)

Comment: Should messages count as definitions? i.e. does `x::foo = "123"` make `x` a defined Symbol?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard good question, probably not for a sake of consistency but I would count it from a practical point of view.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard answer upgraded :)

Comment: Noted.  You already had my vote however. :-)