# Triggering actions when a variable is set

Tags: programming, assignment

Some built-in variables trigger actions when their values are changed:

```
In[17]:= $Assumptions=1
    During evaluation of In[17]:= $Assumptions::bass: 1 is not a well-formed assumption. >>
Out[17]= 1

In[18]:= $Assumptions:=2
    During evaluation of In[18]:= $Assumptions::bass: 2 is not a well-formed assumption. >>
```

(Interestingly the message doesn't trigger if it's set again to the *same* value.)

How can we safely implement something like this?  Are the any built-in hooks for value changes?

---

This is what I currently have.  Does it look safe?  Does anyone foresee problems?  (There's always the least expected thing that goes wrong with these...)

```
$var /: Set[$var, value_] := 
   Block[{$in = True}, 
         Print["$var set to ", value];  $var = value] /; Not@TrueQ[$in]

$var = 6

(*
  $var set to 6
  6
 *)
```

`$in` would of course be in a private context and the same needs to be done for SetDelayed as well.

Comment: Looks safe enough for me. I use the same thing myself when I need this sort of functionality. Of course, I may be unaware of something. Also, if you expose this variable and someone `Block`-s it, then the printing would not work for assignments to it made inside that `Block`.

Comment: I've used this, too, without issue. To add to what Leonid said, there are a couple of cases where the underlying data can be changed, bypassing `Set` and `SetDelayed`, but from what I can tell, those are rare.

Comment: @rcollyer One of such cases is when one uses direct manipulations with `OwnValues`:`OwnValues[$var] = HoldPattern[$var] :> 1` does not trigger anything of course. The good news is that things like `AddTo`, `Increment` etc are top-level, so that the action *is* triggered.

Comment: @rcollyer Another case, perhaps more important in practice, is for part assignments, which are *not* triggered: `$var = Range[10]`, and then `$var[[1]] = 10` goes unnoticed by this triggering mechanism. And in this case `UpValues` can not be used since `$var` would be too deep inside `Part`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin the `Part` example is a good one. I was thinking of some experiences I had with `SparseArray` where I was trying to track changes with this mechanism, and it wasn't captured.

Comment: @rcollyer Actually, for `SparseArray`-s I would imagine that it should be even harder to trigger the part modifications.

Comment: @rcollyer There is yet another set of cases, which are not clear to me how to categorize: you can `Clear`, `ClearAll`, or `Remove` a symbol, you can use `Unset` on it, or you can change its context via `Context[$var]` = "Test`" (for example) - in all of these cases the value of a symbol does change (in the sense that the symbol loses its value, or disappears itself). Of course, in all of these cases the above mechanism is not triggered. Other global properties of a symbol, such as `Options`, `Attributes` etc, may also change - so one must decide should one consider such changes or ignore them.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Exactly. But, for some things it is very workable. I sent you an email detailing the specific issue I had with `SparseArray`. You may find it interesting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### General thoughts

I think that your mechanism is reasonably robust for common use cases, but not fully robust if one wants to take into account all possible ways that the value (or, generally, global properties) of the symbol can be changed in Mathematica.

My current opinion is that making such triggering mechanism fully robust without new system support is very hard or may not be possible at all. Such system support may exist but just not be known to me, however. One place to look at are functions  `` Internal`ValueChangeVeto `` and `` Internal`AddHandler["VetoableValueChange", myVetoFunction] ``. I do know how to make them work with `DownValues`, but not with `OwnValues`, though.

Note that, to make your current mechanism more robust, you will have to add similar definitions not just to `SetDelayed`, but also to `TagSet` and `TagSetDelayed`.  The interesting thing about them is that while the definitions they create may end up being exactly the same as if you used `Set` or `SetDelayed`, they use independent assignment mechanism, so assignment like

```
$var /: $var = 1
```

won't trigger your mechanism.

#### Some analysis

One way to more or less systematically analyze this issue is to look at all built-in functions with `Hold*` attributes. For functions in the `` System` `` context, one can use something like

```
Select[
  Names["System`*"], 
  MemberQ[
    ToExpression[#, StandardForm, Attributes], 
    HoldAll | HoldFirst | HoldRest | HoldAllComplete
  ] &
]
```

I have manually selected a number of functions from this list which affect, directly or indirectly, some of the global properties of the symbol in question. These functions can be divided into several groups according to their actions. Let us list cases where your mechanism does and does not work, based on such division:

- Direct assignment operators: `Set`, `SetDelayed`, `TagSet`, `TagSetDelayed` (and possibly also `UpSet` and `UpSetDelayed`, depending on whether or not you want to account for changes they can introduce). Here also belong `UnSet` and `TagUnset`.

  These functions you can account for explicitly, using definitions similar to what you posted.
- In-place modification operators, such as `AddTo`, `AppendTo`, `Decrement`, `DivideBy`, `Increment`, `PreDecrement`, `PreIncrement`, `PrependTo`, `SubtractFrom`, `TimesBy`.

  Luckily, these are implemented using some of the more fundamental assignment operators, so they are all triggered via your method.
- Operators which clear or remove symbols: `Clear`, `ClearAll`, `Remove`, `Context`. Whether to include or exclude these is a matter of choice, but all of them are ***not*** triggered by your mechanism, but you could add more rules to cover these ones too, in analogy with `Set`. I added `Context` here, because you can change the context of your variable via

  ```
  Context[$var] = "NewContext`"
  ```

  and this effectively removes the variable from its current context.
- Functions providing lower-level access to symbol's properties:`Attributes`, `DefaultValues`, `DownValues`, `FormatValues`, `Messages`, `OwnValues`, `ClearAttributes`, `SetAttributes`, `SubValues`, `UpValues`. Again, depending on how general you want to be, you can include only some of them, but at least you will have to include `OwnValues`.

  Direct assignments involving these functions will ***not*** trigger your mechanism, e.g.:

  ```
  OwnValues[$var] = HoldPattern[$var] :> 10
  ```

  and covering these cases does not seem possible using the `UpValue`-based method.
- Functions such as `Definition`, `FullDefinition`, `` Language`ExtendedDefinition ``, or `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition `` can be assigned to (as you have enlightened us yourself [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19902/copying-one-symbol-into-another/19903#19903)), for example as

  ```
  var1 = 10;
  Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[$var] = 
      Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[var1] /. HoldPattern[var1] :> $var
  ```

  and such assignments will ***not*** be triggered by your method. Again, `UpValues` won't probably help here.
- `Block`: it blocks all definitions attached to a symbol, so if the symbol is `Block`-ed, assignments inside `Block` will ***not*** be triggered.
- Part assignments: these will ***not*** be triggered either. For example:

  ```
  $var = Range[10];
      $var[[1]] = 100
  ```

  This one also seems beyond the reach of the `UpValues`- based method.

I am fairly sure that I missed some more possibilities of value changes for symbols. Some functions in `` Developer` ``, `` Experimental` ``, `` Internal` ``, `` Language` `` and possibly some other contexts may introduce yet more ways to change the values.

#### Conclusions

I think that what you've got can be made good enough with a modest amount of additional rules, and will cover many or most common use cases. However, making this fully robust requires dedicated system support. It may be that such API already exists somehere in one of the contexts I mentioned earlier, but is just not known to me. As I  mentioned already, `` Internal`ValueChangeVeto `` and `` Internal`AddHandler["VetoableValueChange",...] `` may be the right ones to look at, but I don't fully know how they work.

Comment: You may add something about `ValueFunction`http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87554/5478

Comment: @Kuba Don't have the time for it right now. Feel free to edit it in if you think you have something good to add.

Comment: Don't have nothing to add really, maybe let's just leave a link to Karsten's example :)

Comment: @Kuba Just checked: `ValueFunction` doesn't work when we change e.g. `OwnValues` of a symbol directly. So, it doesn't work according the spec, which says "`ValueFunction` takes account of all ways that the value of a symbol can be changed, not just `Set`". So, as of now, I don't see a point to add it to the above, since its presence doesn't contradict my conclusions in the answer above.

Comment: Good find, thanks for checking.